# Significato di metastoria

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, single-words

Buongiorno,

Ho trovato il seguente significato per la parola *metastoria* nel dizionario:

La sfera di ciò che, pur non sovrastando la storia, permane costante nel fluire di questa.

Non capisco questa definizione. Cosa si intende per sfera? Cosa si intende per sovrastare? Io la storia la vedo più come una retta, l'asse del tempo, con punti indicando eventi lungo la storia. Quindi non capisco la sfera e il sovrastare.

Cosa c'è di costate su quest'asse temporaneo, se non la storia in se stessa?

È un termine formale o colloquiale?

Come viene usato questo termine?

Comment: Quale dizionario hai consultato? Suona un po' antiquato.

Comment: Ho usato il Treccani.

Comment: Secondo la [marca d'uso del dizionario De Mauro](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/avvertenze/6), si tratta di un vocabolo "tecnico-specialistico" legato alla filosofia.

Comment: In questo senso, non so se la domanda sia piuttosto fuori tema.

Comment: Sono d'accordo, @Charo: entrare nei dettagli sugli aspetti tecnici, se anche ne fossimo in grado, sarebbe come mettersi a parlare di derivate o di cromosomi. Credo che dobbiamo solo aiutare Jack a destreggiarsi nelle definizioni.

Answer (score 3):

Scopro che quella che citi è una definizione a sua volta storica, data nel 1937 dallo storico Aldo Ferrabino.

“Sfera”, in un contesto così, è un termine molto generico che può voler dire “ambito”, “ambiente”, “situazione”. Si parla di una “sfera di competenza”, della “sfera affettiva” etc. (Non c'è un riferimento diretto alla sfera come figura geometrica.)

Il fatto di non sovrastare la storia presumibilmente esclude elementi (veri o presunti) del tutto metafisici: un dio, il destino e simili.

E quindi, per chi teorizza la metastoria, si tratterebbe degli elementi (forze di qualche tipo, strutture caratteristiche di diverse civiltà...) che farebbero parte della storia e vi rimarrebbero costanti, al di là dei singoli eventi. Comunque questo significato di “metastoria” è specifico del pensiero di [Ferrabino](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/aldo-ferrabino_(Enciclopedia-Italiana)/), che a un certo punto vi unì anche una riflessione religiosa.

Nel [dizionario di De Mauro](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/metastoria) trovi una definizione più moderna: «insieme dei valori immutabili che costituiscono il piano immanente della storia, pur nel divenire continuo e nella molteplicità delle forme; ciò che trascende la storia» (oltre a un diverso concetto dovuto a Croce).

Comment: Grazie per la spiegazione. Rispetto al dizionario De Mauro, mi potresti indicare come tale insieme diventa continuo ea cosa si riferisce la molteplicità delle forme? Mi puoi dare degli esempi di metastorie che trascendono la storia? Grazie.

Comment: Attenzione, @JackMaddington: non è che l'insieme diventa continuo etc. Parafrasando la definizione di De Mauro, la metastoria è un insieme di valori intrinseci nella storia, che non cambiano mentre invece le “forme” (gli eventi, le persone, le nazioni, le culture) si trasformano continuamente e molteplicemente.
Una volta capito l'italiano, le tue congetture sugli esempi etc. valgono le mie, visto che non sono uno storico o un filosofo.

Comment: Di che valori si tratta, sono dei valori matematici o dei valori nel senso di cose che contano, o si riferisce semplicemente a degli schemi che non cambiano. Voglio capire il significato di valori i questo contesto.